# React Facebook Login popping up on page load

Tags: reactjs

I have this code in React:

```
import React from 'react';
import { FACEBOOK_ID } from '../../../config/credentials';
import FacebookLogin from 'react-facebook-login/dist/facebook-login-render-props';

const responseFacebook = response => {
    console.log(response);
};

const FacebookLoginButton = () => (
    <div>
        <FacebookLogin
            appId={FACEBOOK_ID}
            autoLoad
            callback={responseFacebook}
            render={renderProps => (
                <button onClick={e => {
                    console.trace();
                    }
                }>Login via FB</button>
            )}
        />
    </div>
);

export default FacebookLoginButton;
```

This is just a simple react facebook login, now my problem is when I reload my local development site, The facebook authorization always popup on load or when I am currently logged in, it automatically logins the user and returns to the console the information from Facebook. is that the normal behavior of this library? I am new to react so any comments would really be appreciated.

Edit:
I've researched a few videos like this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ea9KyE78qKI&t=10s

It seems like his facebook component popups too when he visit it on his local site at around 12:48 mark but got blocked because Chrome doesn't allow automatic popups.

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make autoLoad as false.

```
    <FacebookLogin
        appId={FACEBOOK_ID}
        autoLoad={false}
        callback={responseFacebook}
        render={renderProps => (
            <button onClick={e => {
                console.trace();
                }
            }>Login via FB</button>
        )}
    />
```

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the autoLoad option will work fine.
By mentioning autoLoad will take autoLoad = true by default.
autoLoad = false or remove autoload will do the same thing.
Hope this will clear more.

```
const FacebookLoginButton = () => (
<div>
    <FacebookLogin
        appId={FACEBOOK_ID}
        callback={responseFacebook}
        render={renderProps => (
            <button onClick={e => {
                console.trace();
                }
            }>Login via FB</button>
        )}
    />
</div>
);
```